# How to move mounted and mapped logical volume from one volume group/physical volume to another

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, lvm

I know that there are many similar questions but none of the solutions works for me as it is a little complicated in my case. I'm sorry if I overlooked one of them.

So I have a Ubuntu server with 2 physical volumes, one is a 4TB HDD and another one is a 250GB SSD.

```
PV /dev/sda3   VG ssd             lvm2 [<217.43 GiB / <197.43 GiB free]
PV /dev/sdb1   VG hdd             lvm2 [<3.64 TiB / 3.63 TiB free]
Total: 2 [3.85 TiB] / in use: 2 [3.85 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

They are mapped into 2 volume groups HDD and SSD respectively.

```
Reading volume groups from cache.
Found volume group "ssd" using metadata type lvm2
Found volume group "hdd" using metadata type lvm2
```

The volume groups are mounted to different paths:

```
ACTIVE            '/dev/ssd/usr' [5.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/ssd/var' [5.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/ssd/home' [5.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/ssd/opt' [5.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/hdd/data' [4.00 GiB] inherit
```

They are also mounted/mapped like this

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 6.3G  7.6M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda1             3.9G  745M  3.2G  19% /
/dev/ssd/usr          4.8G  1.7G  2.9G  37% /usr
tmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M   20K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ssd-opt   4.8G  840M  3.8G  19% /opt
/dev/mapper/ssd-home  4.8G   10M  4.6G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/ssd-var   4.8G  944M  3.7G  21% /var
tmpfs                 6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/hdd-data  3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /data
```

I want to move everything to HDD and divide all available spaces for the logical volumes. I didn't setup the LVM initially so I don't know how to do this.

I have tried using `vgextend` and it gave this error

```
Can't open /dev/sdb1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

And I tried using `pvmove` and it gave this error

```
Failed to find device for physical volume "hdd".
```

I also tried using `vgmerge` and this error came out

```
Logical volumes in "ssd" must be inactive
```

And if I tried to deactivate the logical volume this happened:

```
Logical volume ssd/usr contains a filesystem in use.
Can't deactivate volume group "ssd" with 4 open logical volume(s)
```

So I tried to unmount the filesystem and it won't let me

```
umount: /usr: target is busy.
```

And I don't think I can stop everything that is using the directories without breaking the server... It seems like I need to shut down the server to do that but then I can't run any command if the server is down...

As you can see I am stuck and scratching my head. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did eventually find a way to get it done... In case anyone that comes across this rare case, here's how I did it:

So as stated in the question, I am unable to unmount the logical volume or do anything with it while it is mounted and actively being used. So the only option for me is to boot into `Recovery Mode` where everything will be stopped and only critical stuff is running. That means I can now unmount the logical volume.

So once in the `Recovery Mode`, I created a new logical volume using `lvcreate` on the other volume group that is on another physical volume (its complicated I know).

Then I copy everything in the existing volume (yes haven't unmounted it yet) to the new volume using `cp -rp` (yes there are other ways to do that and you can also just straight-up move them).

Now, I can unmount both volumes and delete the old volume using `lvremove`.

And finally, we go to change the mounting point in the `/etc/fstab` (open with text editor) and it is done.

Reboot back to normal operation mode and it should work perfectly

Hope this helps... but its a rare situation so probably not very helpful